# Low FPS after build for Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, game-development

I have a problem. On my PC FPS in game is OK, but after I build it for Android, it feels wery low.

Unity Version - 2021.3.11f1

**My Settings**

**Build settings**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnz2j.png

**Resolution and Presentation**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdIUl.png

**Other Settings part 1**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXzXI.png

**Other Settings part 2**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBaLj.png

**Other Settings part 3**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC6aN.png

Comment: I suggest using the profiler to figure out what's happening

Comment: In Unity i have 200+ FPS

Answer (score 2):

Phones are most often way slower than pcs. Are you sure its not just the phone being a phone and your app being a bit too performance heavy?

Comment: No, I have a samsung galaxy s20 fe. And game is very primitive. Something wrong with build I guess

Comment: @VolodymyrKaznacheiev Use the Unity profiler in the Unity editor and see if there is any process that takes a substantial amount of time. (“for loops” often cause a large performance decrease)

Comment: I dont even have for loops in my code yet...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).